# Java Scanner escape lines while reading from text file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read the content of a txt file, which contains list of employee details, using Scanner in Java. If I just read the lines and print them, it works just fine.
But the moment I try to store each line in Employee pojo, and add the pojo to empList(ArrayList), Scanner escapes alternate lines and throws exception at the end.

Employee.txt :

```
    1,A,17000
    2,B,11000
    3,C,14000
    4,D,18000
    5,E,19000
    6,F,15000
    7,G,13000
```

Employee.java :

```
    public class Employee {
    
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private long salary;
    
        Employee() {
        }
    
        Employee(int id, String name, long salary) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public long getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }
    
        public void setSalary(long salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class EmployeeDetails {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
            List empList1 = new ArrayList();
            
            File f = new File("Employee.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            String s;
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
                s = sc.nextLine();
                String[] sr = s.trim().split(",");
                Employee emp1 = new Employee(Integer.parseInt(sr[0]), sr[1], Long.parseLong(sr[2]));
                empList1.add(emp1);
            }
            sc.close();
            System.out.println(empList1);
        }
    }
```

Output with Exception:

```
    1,A,17000
    3,C,14000
    5,E,19000
    7,G,13000
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
        at employer.EmployeeDetails.main(EmployeeDetails.java:20)
```

Comment: You call `nextLine` twice in your loop. One line you print, the next line you add to your list.

Comment: It would've been better if this thread was closed (or there was already an accepted answer) because it has already been solved in the "comments" section, which is something we're all trying to avoid.

Comment: @user16320675 Let's just wait for someone capable of doing so.

Comment: It doesn't "escape" them.  But it does skip them.  (I suggest you read an IT dictionary to learn what "escape" means in an IT context.  Or even a plain English context.)

Answer (score 2):

Im just going to copy user tgdavies' answer from the comments so we can mark this closed.

> You call nextLine twice in your loop. One line you print, the next line you add to your list. 
> – tgdavies